# Why does Files and Disks apps think my ZFS filesystems aren't mounted

Tags: gnome, mount, 22.04, zfs

My root and boot partitions are running ZFS, and all is well. EXCEPT that if I try to browse to bpool or rpool in Files (is the app really just called "Files"?!?) I get

[Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p4 at /media/aaron/rpool: unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhuMz.png)

> Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p4 at /media/aaron/rpool: unknown
> filesystem type 'zfs_member'

This is the filesystem that is absolutely mounted and currently running the system. It looks like Files creates a second mount under /media// for browsing, and that doesn't work now?

EDIT: OK, apparently Disks just doesn't do ZFS yet and this is the first time I've looked at it.

These used to work. I suspect they broke when I was playing with creating and deleting snapshots yesterday, although I only did that on rpool and bpool is broken too.

I've found other references to this error, but they're not relevant because the partitions actually are mounting, it's just the GUI apps that are confused.